# Does Product Meta Title default to Product Name if it is empty?

Tags: meta-tags

In doing a fresh install of the latest Magento CE v1.9.1, I saw that the Product Meta Title no longer defaults to the Product Name. As a result, all the Page Titles are showing up with the URL of the page.

Do you guys know if this is a bug, or was this feature to default the name removed? In my earlier v1.7.1, this was working fine.

In the meantime, we implemented the following function that sets the meta title:

class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    /** 
     * Default MAP renderer type
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_mapRenderer = 'msrp_item';

```
/** 
 * Add meta information from product to head block
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{   
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');
    $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
    if ($headBlock) {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
        if ($title) {
            $headBlock->setTitle($title);
        }   
        $keyword = $product->getMetaKeyword();
        $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
        if ($keyword) {
            $headBlock->setKeywords($keyword);
        } elseif ($currentCategory) {
            $headBlock->setKeywords($product->getName());
        }   
        $description = $product->getMetaDescription();
        if ($description) {
            $headBlock->setDescription( ($description) );
        } else {
            $headBlock->setDescription(Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 255));
        }
        if ($this->helper('catalog/product')->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
            $params = array('_ignore_category' => true);
            $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $params));
        }
    }

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to set the `title` as the `meta title`, if `meta title` is not available (null, empty, false, etc.). This is the code from your snippet. I checked CE 1.9, and that's the native behavior.

```
$title = $product->getMetaTitle();
if ($title) { // if B/A, use title as meta title
    $headBlock->setTitle($title);
}
```

Are you sure this block is being used? Do a quick search for the strings `extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` and see if you get any results.